# How to hide Address bar in android chrome browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile-browser

I have tried almost every solution on stackoverflow.com regarding chrome hide address bar but none of them worked
already tried these:

```
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

window.scrollTo(0,1);
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a good way to do this, unless to are OK with asking the user if he/she wants to go full screen - in that case you could use this javascript code:

```
document.body.requestFullscreen();
```

For more info, see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/fullscreen/

Comment: document.documentElement.requestFullscreen();

Comment: No effect on Chrome with Android 8